# Append additional html to cloned object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add additional html in the cloned object.

```
var item = $("#clone")
    .clone(true, true)
    .attr({"id": "citem", "class": "row cartItem_" + item_id})
    .css('display', 'block')
    .appendTo("#all-items");
```

I know about wrap method but that is something else. I want to append html after this cloned object. Or somehow i can manipulate the HTML of the cloned object element.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Unclear.  Question states "add html *in* the clone" then "append html *after* the clone" and title is "append html *to* the clone".  So what exactly are you trying to do.  Could you provide a (simple) before/after?

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. But I want to append html after the clone.

Comment: There seem to be good answers to this question. Will you mark one as accepted?

Comment: @Vixed, can you please explain what are you looking for in the bounty here?

Comment: A valid answer. @Dekel

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "valid answer" since the original question is not so clear and you already added an answer yourself. Lets say I have element `X`. You can to clone that element (lets call it `X_c`), and add some attributes/html to `X_c` and then append the `X_c` to `body` (or some other element)?

Comment: @Vixed, will appreciate if you can comment on my question and also check my answer to see if it gives you what you were looking for.

Comment: @Vixed, any comments? The bounty has 2 more days and you didn't reply yet.

Comment: Don't worry @Dekel

Comment: @Vixed, not related to worry, it just makes sense that you reply and direct the answer if it was correct or not, and if not - what exactly was the problem... If the answer is correct - it would be nice if you can at least vote.

Comment: I'm not looking for the correct answer, mine is also corrected, I'm looking for the best one.

Comment: Can you explain the "best" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to add html *after* the clone:

```
$("#toclone")
    .clone()
    .attr({"id":"cloned"})
    .appendTo("#all-items")
    .after("<div>some more content <em>after</em> the clone</div>");
```

The `.appendTo()` returns the element that was appended, so you can then manipulate it as required, eg using `.after()`

Answer (score 10):

This approach is to explain how the `.clone()` works, and covers all the states you ever mentioned in the question, such as..

1. Creating a clone of a DOM
2. Appending additional raw HTML to a clone
3. Manipulating the clone
4. Manipulating the content in the clone
5. Clone in another clone
6. Appending another clone to a clone
7. Appending HTML after this cloned object

```js
$(function() {
  //! Cloning the HTML
  var $clonedContent = $('.content').clone();

  // Manipulate the cloned element
  // -- Update the existing content
  $clonedContent.find('h5').text("My content just got manipulated");

  // -- Adding raw HTML content
  $clonedContent.append("<small> It's a raw HTML </small>");

  // -- Adding property to an existing content
  $clonedContent.find('small').addClass('make-me-day');

  //! Getting another cloned content
  var $anotherClonedContent = $('.content').clone();
  
  // -- Another manipulation of another cloned content
  $anotherClonedContent.find('h5').text("This is another cloned content");
  
  // -- Manipulate the another cloned content's content
  $anotherClonedContent.find('h5').addClass('make-me-day');

  // -- Add another cloned content to the already manipulated & cloned content.
  $clonedContent.append($anotherClonedContent);

  //! Finally, add the clonedContent to the DOM, aaaand.. add more HTML afterwards.
  $('#main').append($clonedContent, "<em> I added this HTML after the cloned object </em>");
  
});
```

```css
.make-me-day {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="content">
    <h5> Just a simple content </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, the only thing it doesn't show, is how to *"append html after this cloned object"*, which seems to be the question ?

Comment: @adeneo I could've said that it should be that point on my 2nd. But maybe if OP wants to add more HTML after the cloned object which I just added in my 7th. Thanks for pointing that out..

Answer (score 3):

I think that's more easy than you imagine:

```js
$(function(){
  var item_id=0;
  
  // function to clone your element
  var newItem=function(){
    item_id++;
    return $('#clone')
      .clone(true, true)
      .attr({'id':'citem_'+item_id, 'class':'row cartItem_'+item_id})
      .css('display','block')
      .appendTo('#all-items');
  };
  
  // Clone element and edit what you want
  newItem().html('hobby').css('color','blue');

  // Clone element and append what you want
  newItem().append(' - <i>spaghetti</i>');
  
  // You can also find element by id
  $('#citem_2').css('color','red');
  
  //You can add buttons to do it
  $('button:eq(0)').on('click',function(){
    newItem().html('Your <b>html</b> here.');
  });
  $('button:eq(1)').on('click',function(){
    newItem().append(' - Your <b>html</b> here.');
  });
});
```

```html
<button>New clone</button>
<button>New clone + append</button>
<div id="all-items">
  <div id="clone">pizza</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I took a close look to all answers and comments to this bounty question...**

I can see that the bidder is kind of demanding, which is okay since 100 rep. points is valuable.

I think that the question contains two, in fact.

1. How to clone
2. How to *«manipulate the HTML of the cloned object»* - Wasif Iqbal on Sep 22th.

I think the question is intended to get explanations on how to manipulate the clone, not only on creation and appending to somewhere, but also afterward.

I really think my ***very cool example below*** could be a *«valid answer»* - Vixed on Sep 29th.
The other answers were good too, anyway... So a made a supplemental effort.
 ;)

**First explanation of all:**
Cloning an element is done by jQuery [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). So have a nice reading.

**Then:**
jQuery [chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) is nice to append some other stuff «inside» or «before/after» the clone in a concise way, as demonstrated in other answers.

**But to manipulate it afterward**, like in another click event handler...
This is the trick to know, which is not explained in the previous reference:

- You have to make sure to set a **unique `id`** attribute to it, instead of the same `id` as the original.

Because you know that an `id` shall be unique!

> *«One ring to rule them all.
>
>   One ring to find them, one ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.»*
>   
>   - A well known deamon said this while forging a curse...

**Then**... What more explanation could I give if it ain't clear?
Alert reader should have understood everything already.

I made a funny **«clone-and-kill-it-game»** to demontrate cloning and further manipulations.
For the «inspiration», I have to admit that I saw a japaneese zombie movie yesterday night...
lol!

Have fun with this code snippet:
(also on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yapvJy?editors=1010))

```js
// Constants
var number = 1;
var revealed = false;

// The cloning function
$("#cloneIt").click(function(){
    var cloning = $("#Human")
    .clone()
    .attr({"id": "Clone_number_"+number, "class":"clone"})
    .appendTo("#CloneBucket");

    $(this).val("Clone him again! It's fun!");

    number++;
    if(number==4){
        $(".reveal").show();
    }
    if(number==9){
        $(this).val("Enought! This is now illegal.").prop("disabled",true);
    }

    // Add them to select
    var options="<option disabled selected class='deceased'>KILL THEM!</option>";
    for (i=1;i<number;i++){
        if( $("#CloneBucket").children().eq(i-1).hasClass("dead") ){
            options += "<option value='"+i+"' class='deceased'>Clone #"+i+"</option>";
        }else{
            options += "<option value='"+i+"'>Clone #"+i+"</option>";
        }
    }
    $("#cloneSelect").html(options);

    if(revealed){
        reveal();   // Sub function to add clones to a select element.
    }
});

// Reveal clone numbers
$(".reveal").click(function(){
    reveal();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".reveal").val("Kill a clone! (While it's not illegal!)").removeClass("reveal").addClass("shoot");
    },50);

});

// Kill button
$("#page").on("click",".shoot",function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled",true).val("Select one");
    $("#cloneSelect").show();
});

// Select kill target
$("#cloneSelect").change(function(){
    var thisCloneIs = parseInt($(this).val());
    var niceShot = "#Clone_number_"+thisCloneIs;
    $(niceShot).css({"opacity":0.3,"color":"red"});
    $(niceShot+" .definition").html("I was the number"+thisCloneIs).parent().addClass("dead");

    // Redish the option
    $(this).find("option").eq(thisCloneIs).prop("disabled",true).addClass("deceased");
    $(this).find("option").eq(0).prop("selected",true);

    // Bravo!
    var allDead = [];
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#cloneSelect").find("option").each(function(index){

            if( $("#cloneSelect").find("option").eq(index).hasClass("deceased") ){
                allDead.push(true);
            }else{
                allDead.push(false);
            }
        });

        if( allDead.indexOf(false)==-1 ){

            // Reset this super gaming experience for a new.
            $("#CloneBucket").html("");
            $(".shoot").addClass("reveal").removeClass("shoot").val("Reveal clone numbers!").prop("disabled",false).hide();
            $("#cloneIt").val("Clone again?").prop("disabled",false);
            $("#cloneSelect").html("").hide();
            revealed = false;
            number = 1;
        }
    },50);
});

function reveal(){
    $(".clone .definition").each(function(index){
        var cloneIndex = index+1;   // zero-based
        $(this).html("I'm the number "+cloneIndex);
        revealed = true;
    });
}
```

```css
img{
    width:60px;
}
div{
    text-align:center;
}
.reveal{
    display:none;
}
#CloneBucket div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
#CloneBucket{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
select{
    display:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.deceased{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
    <input type="button" id="cloneIt" value="Want to clone him?"><br>
    <br>
    <div id="Human">
        <img src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/10/10522.svg"><br>
        <span class="definition">I'm a real human!</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="reveal" value="Reveal clone numbers!">
    <select id="cloneSelect"></select>

    <div id="CloneBucket"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to add an `id`, unique or otherwise - that just confuses the issue.  And the way you've used `id` in this example code would be better served with a `data-` attribute.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Thanks for your comment on that old answer.... But I don't get the point about an advantage for a `data` attribute (for a single *`id`* info) over the `id` attribute. I don't get the confusion issue.

Comment: My bad - I took this *'you have to assign a unique id'* as meaning you *must* assign the id in-order to manipulate it after, which you don't.   But in fact that line refers to this part of the question `attr({"id": "citem",` which could potentially be assigning the same ID multiple times - or not, as there's only one clone call and the original id was `#clone`.

Comment: data vs id - semantics.   It's like `<i>` vs `<em>` or onlick vs js-assigned event handlers.  or POST vs PUT.  While you *can* use one thing for something else, that's not what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Still waiting for clarification in the comments, but I think this solution is what you are looking for:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#clone').clone()
    .append('<span style="color:red;">some other elements</span>')
    .removeAttr('id')
    .appendTo('#all-items');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click to clone</button>
<div id="all-items">
  <div id="clone">pizza</div>
</div>
```

Since the `appendTo` returns the original element that was appended, you can use `after` on the returned value to add some new element after the cloned element that you just appended:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#clone').clone()
    .append('<span style="color:red;">some other elements</span>')
    .removeAttr('id')
    .addClass('cloned')
    .appendTo('#all-items')
    .after('<div>this element was added after the cloned element (no blue border here)</div>');
});
```

```css
.cloned {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click to clone</button>
<div id="all-items">
  <div id="clone">pizza</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One can add to a collection at any time using jQuery's [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) function.
This effectively adds to the collection, placing whatever is passed to `add()` after the clone itself, as opposed to `append` which places the content *inside* the clone, answering the question

> *"I want to append html after this cloned object"*

```js
var more1 = $('<span />', {html : '<em> and will</em>'}); // element(s) to add
var more2 = '<span> happen again....</span>'; // or strings of HTML for that matter

    
var item  = $("#clone").clone(true, true)
                       .attr({"id": "citem"})
                       .show()
                       .add(more1) // add whatever after the clone
                       .add(more2) // before appending everything
                       .appendTo("#all-items");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="clone">
    <span>All of this has happened before</span>
</span>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="all-items"><!-- clone goes here --></div>
```

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   `.add()` method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method.
>   The argument to `.add()`
>   can be pretty much anything that `$()` accepts, including a jQuery
>   selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.
>
> example : `$("p").clone().add("<span>Again</span>").appendTo(document.body);`

`add()` does not change the original collection, but returns a new collection, so if not chaining directly on the modified collection, one has to store that collection

```
var clone   = $('#elem').clone(true, true);
var changed = clone.add('<div>new content</div>'); // clone is not changed
```

Manipulating the content inside a clone is done in the exact same way as manipulating any other collection with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Post something link this

```
var clone = parent.find('.divclone').clone();
clone.removeClass('identifier');
clone.removeClass('hide');
//.. code changes for the new clone
clone.find(".link-slug").attr('href',invstr_val.slug_url);
// append it again to the original 
clone.insertAfter(parent.find(".divclone"));
```